# Apply class to all classes if it cotains a certain string

Tags: javascript

I have a profile card that contains a job role inside a span, and I'm trying to get the content of the job role using textContent, and if it matches a certain word, I want to add a class to the span

```
<span class="jobrole">Manager</span>
```

Here is the javascript:

```
var text = document.querySelector(".jobrole").textContent;
var job = document.querySelector(".jobrole");
      if (text == "Manager") {
        for (var i = 0; i < job.length; ++i) { 
          job.classList.add("manager");
        }
}
```

However, it's not applying the manager class to any on the spans that contain the string "manager"

Comment: You'll need to start by using `querySelectorAll` instead of `querySelector`, only that will return a list of elements. And then you'll need to get the `.textContent` of each of them, not just of the first one.

Comment: what if the `textContent` has words along with `manger` like `QA Manager`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to apply to only first found element with `Manager` content, you should implement this way

```js
var job = document.querySelector(".jobrole");
var text = job.textContent;

if (text === "Manager") {
  job.classList.add("manager");
}
```

```html
<span class="jobrole">Manager</span>
```

If you want to have many more similar elements with `Manager` content, you should use `querySelectorAll` instead

```js
var jobs = document.querySelectorAll(".jobrole");
for (var i = 0; i < jobs.length; i++) {
  var text = jobs[i].textContent;
  if (text === "Manager") {
    jobs[i].classList.add("manager");
  }
}
```

```html
<span class="jobrole">Manager</span>
<span class="jobrole">Manager</span>
```

One further case is that you want to check multiple manager types like `Store Manager`, `Operation Manager`, etc. With this pattern, you can use `.includes`

```js
var jobs = document.querySelectorAll(".jobrole");
for (var i = 0; i < jobs.length; i++) {
  var text = jobs[i].textContent;
  if (text && text.toLowerCase().includes("manager")) { //ignore case sensitive for `text` which means `manager` is also a match
    jobs[i].classList.add("manager");
  }
}
```

```html
<span class="jobrole">Store Manager</span>
<span class="jobrole">Operation Manager</span>
```

Comment: if (text == "Manager" || "DTS Manager") {
    jobs[i].classList.add("manager");
  }

Would this effect job roles that contain "DTS Manager" aswell?

Comment: the correct condition should be `if (text === "Manager" || text === "DTS Manager")`, but if you want to have similar text like `A Manager`, `B Manager`, etc. You can check like this `if(text.includes("Manager"))` @Colourcloud

Answer (score 0):

**1)** If you just want to add a class that has `textContent` as `manager` then you can also use regex here as:

```
textContent.match(/^manager$/i)    // case-sensitive
```

```js
const allJobRoleEl = document.querySelectorAll(".jobrole");
allJobRoleEl.forEach((jobRoleEl) => {
  const textContent = jobRoleEl.textContent;
  if (textContent.match(/^manager$/i)) {
    jobRoleEl.classList.add("manager");
  }
});
```

```css
.manager {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
  padding: 0.25rem;
  margin: 0.5rem;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
```

```html
<span class="jobrole">Manager</span>
<span class="jobrole">Developer</span>
<span class="jobrole"> QA Manager </span>
<span class="jobrole"> Dev Manager</span>
```

**NOTE:** But If you want to add class to all those elements that `contain` text `manager` then you can do as:

```
textContent.match(/^manager$/i)    // case-sensitive
```

```js
const allJobRoleEl = document.querySelectorAll(".jobrole");
allJobRoleEl.forEach((jobRoleEl) => {
  const textContent = jobRoleEl.textContent;
  if (textContent.match(/manager/i)) {
    jobRoleEl.classList.add("manager");
  }
});
```

```css
.manager {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
  padding: 0.25rem;
  margin: 0.5rem;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
```

```html
<span class="jobrole">Manager</span>
<span class="jobrole">Developer</span>
<span class="jobrole"> QA Manager </span>
<span class="jobrole"> Dev Manager</span>
```